# php pdo $_post insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sqlArray = array();
$nameArray = array();
$valueArray = array();

 foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
  $nameArray[] = $name;
  $valueArray[] = $value;
 }

$names = implode(', ', $nameArray);
$values = implode(', ', ':'.$nameArray);
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers ( ".$names." ) VALUES ( ".$values." )";

print_r($sql);
$addRandom = $pdo->prepare( $sql );

 foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
  $addRandom->bindValue($name, $value);
 }

$boolean=$addRandom->execute();

if($boolean){
 echo 'INSERTED';
}else{
 echo 'FAILED';
}
```

i am facing some problem while running this code.. please help me to fix this. showing error in implode(', ', ':'.$nameArray)

Comment: ` $values`  = `implode(', ', ':'.$nameArray);` only 1 parameter. Shoulde be `implode(', ', $nameArray);`

Comment: Please indent your code for better readability and explain how the error actually shows. Then formulate a question and adjust the title. Thank you and feel welcome at SO!

Comment: just read a manual on how to use `implode`

Comment: `showing error in implode(', ', ':'.$nameArray)`: if you gave us the error it would have been a hint. And you'll probably have found what the problem is. `':'.$nameArray`: You are trying to concatenate a string with an array. Explain what you want to do here. Quite sure you want to replace this line with `$values = implode(', ', $valueArray);`.

Comment: the $nameArray contains like this 'first_name, uid, phone, last_name, street, street_no, apartment, city, phone2, phone3, age, gender, household, main_lang, lang2, lang3, field16, test, test2'. i need to add colon on each strings like ':first_name,:uid,...'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$fields = array_keys($_POST);
if (!empty($fields)) {
    $names = implode('`, `', $fields);
    $values = implode(', :', $fields);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers ( `".$names."` ) VALUES ( :".$values." )";
    print_r($sql);

    $addRandom = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $addRandom->bindValue(":{$field}", $_POST[$field]);
    }

    $boolean = $addRandom->execute();
    if ($boolean){
        echo 'INSERTED';
    } else {
        echo 'FAILED';
    }   
}
```